# Save history for a specific command elsewhere than .bash_history

Tags: linux, bash, input-history

By default, command history is stored in `~/.bash_history` file.

I want to save the history for a specific command elsewhere than `~/.bash_history` every time the command is called, like in a file `~/.specific-command-history`.

I don't want to run grep to search for a specific command neither exclude it from `~/.bash_history`, I just wanted to have a history for a specific command to be automatically stored in other file as well as in `~/.bash_history`.

Any thoughts about that?

Comment: You may write a wrapper around your command, for example: wrap ls: mv /bin/ls /bin/ls.orig . Edit /bin/ls as a shell script, that will write the line to the ~/.specific-command-history . Then call /bin/ls.orig $@

Answer (score 1):

You could create and run an `anacron` script, even if at a set time the server was switched off, when the server is switched on, `anacron` will run the script.

The `anacron` script would `grep` the file with the command you are looking for, and then use `cut`, and then append the file you would like to paste the lines into.